# replace greek number format (1.000,00)

Tags: javascript, json, replace

i have a json o take from a csv and looks like this:

```
json_obj : {"id, name, num1, num2" :"1, name111, 2, 1.000,12" }
{   "id, name, num1, num2" :"2, name222, 34, 5.124,56" }
{   "id, name, num1, num2" :"3, name333, 5.232,56, 1.123,22" }
```

The problem is that when i parse the json, it understands the numbers in num1 & num2 properties as strings because of the greek number format (1.000,00) . I try to replace "." with"" and "," with "." in order to identify them as numbers with this code:

```
var getdata = JSON.parse(response.responseText); //takes the data of the csv
var stringified = JSON.stringify(getdata);
stringified = stringified.replace(/\./g, "").replace(/\,/g, ".");
var resource = JSON.parse(stringified);
```

but it replaces also the "," of the json, so i get nothing. How can i replace only the fields of the properties num1 & num2 ?

Comment: Is this a one-off task (in which case string manipulation should be good enough) or do you expect to need to handle other locale-specific currency formats?

Comment: No only this kind of format I expect to change. But I must replace at once all the fields of the properties.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work:

```
var parsedNumber = +'1.000,12'.replace('.', '').replace(',', '.')
```

Comment: Hi.Thanks for your reply. I need to replace all the fields at once...not tell what value to replace because I assume that I don t know what the csv gives me.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```js
var s = `{"id, name, num1, num2" :"1, name111, 2, 1.000,12" }
{   "id, name, num1, num2" :"2, name222, 34, 5.124,56" }
{   "id, name, num1, num2" :"3, name333, 5.232,56, 1.123,22" }
{   "id, name, num1, num2" :"4, name444, 232,56, 123,22" }
{   "id, name, num1, num2" :"4, name444, 12.345.232,56, 123,22" }`;
var res = s.replace(/(?:(\d+)\.)?(?:(\d+)\.)?(\d+),(\d+)/g, "$1$2$3.$4");
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `str.split([separator[, limit]])` function on every item and set `', '` as *separator* and `4` as *limit*. But you exactly need to know, that all fields are *separated* by *comma-space*. Or other option would be put all values to `”'”`, so then it would be not just plain `1.000,12` but `'1.000,12'`. And then you could easily parse it with *regExp*

Answer (score 0):

```
enter code here<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.simplemobiletools.dialer"
android:installLocation="auto">

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).